# directive with validation wrapper around it

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive which will have the complete bootstrap form field layout along with form validation messages etc along with controlling the html from the javascript model definition, i thought it would be simple but doesn't seems like that now.

currently i have write below template for every single field:

```
'<div ng-form="myform">' +
        '<div class="control-group" class="{{options.class}}" >' +
        '<div class="control-label">{{options.label}} {{options.required ? "*" : ""}} </div>' +
        '<div class="controls">';

    html += '<input type="number" name="myfield" placeholder="{{options.placeholder}}" ng-required="options.required" ' +
        'ng-pattern="{{options.pattern}}" ng-minlength="{{options.minlength}}" ng-maxlength="{{options.maxlength}}" ' +
        'ng-readonly="options.readonly" autofocus="options.autofocus" ng-change="ngChange"  autocomplete="off" data-ng-model="ngModel"/>'

    html += '<div class="field-validation-error" data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$invalid && myform.myfield.$dirty"> ' +
                '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.required ">{{options.label}} is required!!!</div>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.pattern">{{options.patternMessage}}</div>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.minlength">{{options.label}} should have atleast {{options.minlength}} character/s.</div>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.maxlength">{{options.label}} can have maximum {{options.maxlength}} character/s.</div>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.min">{{options.label}} cannot have value less than {{options.min}}</div>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.max">{{options.label}} cannot have value greater than {{options.max}}</div>' +
            '</div>';
```

and i have corresponding object in the controller.

```
  $scope.fields = {
             name : {lable: "Name", required: true, min-length=5}
  }
```

so passing this object to the directive and then getting the template generated as per the field details should work, but not able to achieve end result. i have tried various approaches.

1. have separate directives for the template and for the input tag

   a. have a directive 'E' which will generate the input tag, but ng-change and ng-model are     not in sync for some reason, check this: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/5M6U8f?p=preview)

   b. have a directive 'A' which will add the ng-minlength, ng-maxlength attrs to the input tags, the validation does not get fired. check this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmL6ML?p=preview)
2. have everything in one directive, but then how do i pass the ng-change, ng-blur, typeahead from my directive to the input tag, its not ideal to keep getting every thing on scope and keep adding it to input.

Can someone please guide me how can i achieve the end result..
Options 2 worked for most of the cases, but started giving problems as scenarios increased and this way i would like to avoid at all costs. 
hence i went back to first implementation i.e. 2 directive approach, one directive for generating input tags and another for layout and validations

but then if i have directive for input tags as 'E' then all the ng-change & ng-model will need to have the $parent appended because i am getting options through scope, so then again then end user of directive will have remember to pass $parent for every interaction with the scope, which looses on transparency level. so going with the 'A' directive seems to be the best approach.

Can someone help me in solving problem 1.b which is why are validations not working if i have ng-form on a different directive than the input tags directive (i know the validations are done in compile phase and not link phase)

or if someone can point me to something similar which tries to achieve what a am trying. 
Note: I had look at formly-angular but it also has the problem of not having ng-change etc on the input. are there any other similar solutions.

Comment: Plnker doesn't seem to be working :(. Is it just me?

Comment: plunkers are working.. just confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to compile the element

```
$compile(element)(scope)
```

currently as you are not compiling the angular wont know of the changes that u made in the dom